# SSRS Reports - Formatting Date Column using expression

Tags: reporting-services, date-formatting

I am using SSAS cube to display data in my report. There is a date column in the cube which may be blank. If it is blank I need to display blank otherwise I need to format it as "MM-yyyy". I am using the below mentioned expression in the column.

```vb
=IIf(Trim(Fields!Chargeoff.Value) = "", "", 
     Format(CDate(Fields!Chargeoff.Value), "MM-yyyy"))
```

The rows which have date values are perfect with the correctly formatted date being displayed. However for blank rows, it displays error saying

> The Value expression for the textrun ‘Chargeoff.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: Conversion from string "" to type 'Date' is not valid

I tried with IsNothing, Null and everything else that came to my mind but could not get to display blank.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this?

**Update**

I actually formatted my date in SSAS instead of SSRS.. That did the trick for me..

Answer (score 2):

```
=IIF(CDATE(IIF(TRIM(Fields!RequiredStart.Value).ToString().Length = 0,
"1/1/0001",
Fields!RequiredStart.Value)).ToString() = CDATE("01/01/0001"),
"",
Format(CDATE(IIF(TRIM(Fields!RequiredStart.Value).ToString().Length = 0,
"1/1/0001",
Fields!RequiredStart.Value)), "dd-MMM-yyyy"))
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

try putting and Empty Date in for the output instead of an empty string. `00-0000`  it is looking for a Date and you give it an empty String. I would imagine that you either have to give it an `empty date` or a `Default Date`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but the problem I fear is that the "IIf" condition itself is not evaluating to true for blank cells since the error message says that it is trying to convert "" to Date which is not supported. However I tried using "00-0000" in place of "" but it doesn't work.

Comment: please add an update to your post, so that others know that you have tried that. have you tried a different Date Format?

Comment: I actually formatted my date in SSAS instead of SSRS.. That did the trick for me..

Comment: @user1627749 post what you did and mark it as an answer, so that when other people have the same problem they can what you did to fix it.